# Automating an AutoCompleteExtender with Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, autocomplete

I am trying to properly automate an auto complete field. 
I had a work around by using a lot of Thread.Sleep but this is slow and temperamental at best.

I have found this snippit of code a couple of times which looks like it will do the trick

```
driver.findElement(By.id("your searchBox")).sendKeys("your partial keyword");
Thread.sleep(3000);
List <WebElement> listItems = driver.findElements(By.xpath("your list item locator"));
listItems.get(0).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("your searchButton")).click();
```

However I am hitting an issue with the `listItems.Get` where I am getting the following message

```
'List<IWebElement>' does not contain a definition for 'Get' and no extension method 'Get' accepting a first argument of type 'List<IWebElement>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I've done some hunting on Google and cant see if I am missing a dll or if `get` has been replaced so I have been unable to get this working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `listItems.ElementAt (0)`. You may need to add `using System.Linq`

Comment: Glad to be of help :)